# Is Java 9 on Windows available in a 32 bit version?

Tags: java, x86

This page on the Oracle site suggests there are 32 bit and 64 bit versions of Java 9: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-microsoft-windows-platforms.htm

However on the download pages for both the JRE and JDK I can only find 64 bit versions: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk9-downloads-3848520.html

When can I find definitive information as to whether there is a 32-bit version of Java 9?

Comment: Who is still using a 32-bit operating system?  Why would you want to?

Comment: Some customers of my company's desktop app.

Comment: Always the user....

Comment: You should be telling your customers that they need to update to a 64 bit operating system.  Please don't tell us they're running Windows XP.

Comment: @duffymo: I think some low-memory and/or low-storage netbook / tablet devices ship 32-bit OSes.  Support for 32-bit user-space is still necessary in the Windows world, because people still have legacy binary-only stuff, and some people still only ship 32-bit binaries.  So a 64-bit OS needs to ship 32 and 64-bit libraries (and potentially have them both loaded into RAM).  If there was a good 32-bit pointers in 64-bit ABI, that would make 32-bit user-space fully obsolete for performance reasons, but still not for supporting legacy binaries.  Anyway, 64-bit OSes can't drop 32, so it costs space.

Comment: I think it *sucks* that anyone's still using a 32-bit x86 kernel in 2017, outside of http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/, but I understand why some device vendors might think it was a good idea.  I think MS also used to charge less for 32-bit Windows, which I think was a terrible idea.  Giving anyone any kind of incentive to ship a 32-bit OS is a bad idea.

Comment: Your points are good, @PeterCordes, but I still disagree.  Nobody should be running Java on a 32 bit operating system.  Oracle agrees: There's no version available.  It's just a poor excuse for a bad client to put off upgrading for another year.

Comment: @duffymo: good, I'm glad some major vendors are dropping support for 32-bit OSes, so 32-bit OSes are finally going to stop being a valid option soon, and maybe more developers can finally stop caring about making versions of their software for obsolete 32-bit x86.